# Como hago para que el color blanco que sobresale de la imagen sea el mismo color que el background del body?

Tags: css, flexbox, img, body, gradient

quería saber si me pueden ayudar con lo siguiente. En el body puse un gradiante, pero cuando coloco las imagenes, lo que sobresale de ellas, queda en blanco, y no se ve afectado por el color que apliqué en el gradiante. Alguien sabe como hacer para que en las imagenes que puse queden del mismo color que puse en el body?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Muchas gracias por la ayuda! Terminé utilizando Adobe photoshop para sacarle el background a las imagenes y los pasé a formato png.

Comment: ¿Te aseguraste de que las imágenes que estás utilizando estén en formato png con fondo transparente?

Comment: Hola buenos dias Martin asi mismo como te comenta @Kododo verifica bien tus imagenes si estan en formato PNG, osea su fondo transparente y si estan en PNG verifica si en tu proyecto le a asignado el formato PNG, Puesda que halla escrito -- foto.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacerlo de la siguiente forma con `css`:

```
.removeBg {
  filter: brightness(1.1);
  mix-blend-mode: normal;
}
```

Aunque lo más recomendado sería utilizar el software llamado **[remove.bg](https://www.remove.bg/es)**, de la cual transforma la imágen en PNG con el **background** removido y estas imágenes lo reutilizarías en tu proyecto.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Terminé usando Adobe photoshop y le saqué el background a todas las imagenes.

Comment: También sería otra buena opción, saludos!